# Iterate nested JSON in python to get tall dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python's json operations. I have this JSON that I want to convert into a tall dataframe:

```
[{
    "name": "company1",
    "columns": [{
        "name": "Col1",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "isHidden": "True",
        "sourceColumn": "cp1",
        "sourceProviderType": "int"
    }, {
        "name": "Col2",
        "dataType": "string",
        "sourceColumn": "bar"
    }, {
        "name": "Col3",
        "dataType": "string",
        "isHidden": "True",
        "sourceColumn": "zappa"
    }],
    "partitions": [{
        "name": "Col1",
        "dataView": "full",
        "source": {
            "type": "query",
            "query": "SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta ",
            "dataSource": "kappa"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "name": "company2",
    "columns": [{
        "name": "bar",
        "dataType": "int64",
        "sourceColumn": "jaa",
        "sourceProviderType": "categorical"
    }, {
        "name": "zoo",
        "dataType": "string",
        "isHidden": "True",
        "sourceColumn": "cp1"
    }],
    "partitions": [{
        "name": "bar",
        "dataView": "full",
        "source": {
            "type": "query",
            "query": "SELECT foo,bar FROM foo.beta ",
            "dataSource": "pqr"
        }
    }]
}]
```

I wanted to iterate for each array item .
Expected output is :

[image]

```
name,columns.name,columns.dataType,columns.isHidden,columns.sourceColumn,columns.sourceProviderType,partitions.name,partitions.dataView,partitions.source.type,partitions.source.query
Company1,Col1,int64,TRUE,cp1,int,Col1,full,query,"SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta"
Company1,Col2,string,NULL,bar,NULL,Col1,full,query,"SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta"
Company1,Col3,string,TRUE,zappa,NULL,Col1,full,query,"SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta"
Company2,bar,int64,NULL,jaa,categorical,bar,full,query,"SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.beta"
Company2,zoo,string,TRUE,cp1,NULL,bar,full,query,"SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.beta"
```

I used json_normalize() but without much help. I have two issues, 
1) 'columns' doesn't have fix number of items . I want to fill them with NULL's.
2) Iterate  all 'partition' items  for each company .

Help appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data always look like this, you can do `json_normalize` on the values of your `json`, and then `concat` them all:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s).explode("columns").reset_index(drop=True) #s being your json

print (pd.concat([df["name"],
                  json.json_normalize(df['columns']).add_prefix("columns."),
                  json.json_normalize(df['partitions'].str[0]).add_prefix("partitions.")],
                  axis=1))
```

Result:

```
       name columns.name columns.dataType columns.isHidden columns.sourceColumn columns.sourceProviderType partitions.name partitions.dataView partitions.source.type          partitions.source.query partitions.source.dataSource
0  company1         Col1            int64             True                  cp1                        int            Col1                full                  query  SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta                         kappa
1  company1         Col2           string              NaN                  bar                        NaN            Col1                full                  query  SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta                         kappa
2  company1         Col3           string             True                zappa                        NaN            Col1                full                  query  SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta                         kappa
3  company2          bar            int64              NaN                  jaa                categorical             bar                full                  query    SELECT foo,bar FROM foo.beta                           pqr
4  company2          zoo           string             True                  cp1                        NaN             bar                full                  query    SELECT foo,bar FROM foo.beta                           pqr
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following:

```
import json
with open('temp.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = df.explode(column="columns").reset_index()
df["partitions"] = df["partitions"].apply(lambda x: x[0])
temp = df["columns"].apply(pd.Series)
temp.columns = "columns_" + temp.columns
temp2 = df["partitions"].apply(pd.Series)
temp2.columns = "partitions_" + temp2.columns
temp3 = temp2["partitions_source"].apply(pd.Series)
temp3.columns = "partitions_" + temp3.columns
new_df = pd.concat([df.name, temp, temp2[["partitions_name", "partitions_dataView"]], temp3], axis=1)
```

and the result is :

```
     name columns_name  ...                 partitions_query partitions_dataSource
0  company1         Col1  ...  SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta                  kappa
1  company1         Col2  ...  SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta                  kappa
2  company1         Col3  ...  SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta                  kappa
3  company2          bar  ...    SELECT foo,bar FROM foo.beta                    pqr
4  company2          zoo  ...    SELECT foo,bar FROM foo.beta                    pqr
```

and for instance for columns where you wanted NaNs:

```
0    True
1     NaN
2    True
3     NaN
4    True
Name: columns_isHidden, dtype: object
```

I replaced dots with "_" so that you can still access columns with `new_df.columns_isHidden` otherwise it would have looked like attributes.

Hope it helps

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks Raphaele.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions could be used here to get data from the columns and partitions keys, then merged to form one table.

```
columns = [pd.DataFrame(ent['columns'])
           .add_prefix('column.')
           .assign(company=ent['name']) for ent in data]

#concatenate comprehension output
columns = pd.concat(columns)
columns

#run comprehension here as well
#however json_normalize is used, since there is a nested dict in the dict
partitions = [json_normalize(ent['partitions'])
              .add_prefix('partition.')
              .assign(company = ent['name']) for ent in data]

partitions = pd.concat(partitions)

 #merge columns and partition on the company column    
res = columns.merge(partitions,how='left', on='company')

res

   column.name  column.dataType column.isHidden column.sourceColumn column.sourceProviderType   company partition.name  partition.dataView  partition.source.type   partition.source.query  partition.source.dataSource
0   Col1          int64         True               cp1              int company1    Col1    full    query   SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta  kappa
1   Col2          string        NaN                bar  NaN company1    Col1    full    query   SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta  kappa
2   Col3          string        True               zappa    NaN company1    Col1    full    query   SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo.zeta  kappa
3   bar           int64         NaN                jaa  categorical company2    bar full    query   SELECT foo,bar FROM foo.beta    pqr
4   zoo           string        True               cp1  NaN company2    bar full    query   SELECT foo,bar FROM foo.beta    pqr
```

Comment: Thanks semmywemmy .